# Convert distance list to distance matrix

Tags: r, distance-matrix

In R, I have a data.frame showing the distance between pairs of nodes:

```
dl <- data.frame(
  a = c('a','a','a','b','b','c'),
  b = c('b','c','d','c','d','d'),
  dist = c(1,2,3,2,1,2)
)
```

I want to convert this to a distance matrix, with the diagonal set to zero and the upper triangle set to NA, since the distances are symmetrical:

```
dm <- data.frame(
  a = c(0,2,3,2),
  b = c(NA, 0, 2, 1),
  c = c(NA, NA, 0, 2),
  d = c(NA, NA, NA, 0),
  row.names = c('a','b','c','d')
) %>% as.matrix()
```

My real data is very large, so computational efficiency is key. The only solution I can come up with myself involves either looping or using `igraph` to first convert the list to a graph, and then converting that graph to matrix, and thats not really ideal given the size of my data. The input is a data.frame since node-ids are text while distances are numeric, and the desired output is a matrix since speed is key.

Comment: One question. Is your desired output a matrix with the diagonal 0 and the low and upper triangle set as NA, right?

Comment: @Isaac, yes thats the desired output

Answer (score 5):

Here are some base R options

## Use `xtabs`

```
v <- unique(unlist(dl[-3]))
dl[-3] <- lapply(dl[-3], factor, levels = v)
dm <- unclass(t(xtabs(dist ~ ., dl)))
dm[upper.tri(dm)] <- NA
```

which gives

```
> dm
   a
b   a  b  c  d
  a 0 NA NA NA
  b 1  0 NA NA
  c 2  2  0 NA
  d 3  1  2  0
attr(,"call")
xtabs(formula = dist ~ ., data = dl)
```

## Use `as.dist`

```
v <- unique(unlist(dl[-3]))
dl[-3] <- lapply(dl[-3], factor, levels = v)
dm <- as.dist(t(xtabs(dist ~ ., dl)), diag = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> dm
  a b c d
a 0
b 1 0
c 2 2 0  
d 3 1 2 0
```

## Use `matrix`

```
v <- unique(unlist(dl[-3]))
dm <- `diag<-`(matrix(NA, length(v), length(v), dimnames = list(v, v)), 0)
dm[as.matrix(rev(dl[-3]))] <- dl$dist
```

which gives

```
> dm
  a  b  c  d
a 0 NA NA NA
b 1  0 NA NA
c 2  2  0 NA
d 3  1  2  0
```

Comment: does the order of the unique values in v matter? I can see that `v <- unique(unlist(dl[-3]))` takes some time to compute in my real data, and I have them stored elsewhere already, but not in the same order as they are returned when i do `v <- unique(unlist(dl[-3]))`. The order of rows/columns in the resulting distance matrix does not matter for me, as long as the distance between node A and node B is the same, i.e., it does not matter what rownumber node A has.

Comment: @EmilA I don't think the order matters

Comment: One more question: If the id variable is already numeric, is the factoring step `dl[-3] <- lapply(dl[-3], factor, levels = v)` necessary, or can I go directly at `dm <- unclass(t(xtabs(dist ~ ., dl)))`

Comment: @EmilA `factor` is to ensure you have the same levels in row and column names for the resulting `dm`. If you skip that step, you will see that the row and column names are not the same.

Answer (score 4):

Building a sparse matrix will be fast.

```
library(Matrix)
u <- unique(unlist(dl[,1:2]))
dm <- sparseMatrix(match(dl$b, u), match(dl$a, u), x = dl$dist, repr = "T",
                   dims = rep(length(u), 2), dimnames = list(u, u))

dm
#> 4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
#>   a b c d
#> a . . . .
#> b 1 . . .
#> c 2 2 . .
#> d 3 1 2 .
```

If `dist` objects will work, you can build one directly. This will also be very fast. (This assumes `dl` is sorted by `a` then `b`.)

```
dm <- dl$dist
class(dm) <- "dist"
attr(dm, "Labels") <- unique(unlist(dl[,1:2]))
attr(dm, "Size") <- length(attr(dm, "Labels"))
attr(dm, "Diag") <- FALSE
attr(dm, "Upper") <- FALSE
attr(dm, "method") <- "euclidean"

dm
#>   a b c
#> b 1    
#> c 2 2  
#> d 3 1 2
```